# Flutter : InAppWebview crashing when close it

Tags: flutter, crash, java-native-interface, flutter-inappwebview

We have tried: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112542 this solution it works for most devices but not working for some device

Crash Details:

```
[ERROR:flutter/fml/platform/android/jni_util.cc(204)] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform view hasn't been initialized from the platform view channel.
E/flutter (25229):     at io.flutter.plugin.platform.q.Q(Unknown Source:96)
E/flutter (25229):     at io.flutter.plugin.platform.q.Z(Unknown Source:3)
E/flutter (25229):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.onDisplayPlatformView(Unknown Source:19)
E/flutter (25229):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (25229):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:340)
E/flutter (25229):     at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:169)
E/flutter (25229):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
E/flutter (25229):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8250)
E/flutter (25229):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (25229):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
E/flutter (25229):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1049)
E/flutter (25229): 
F/flutter (25229): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni_impl.cc(1486)] Check failed: fml::jni::CheckException(env). 
F/crashpad(25798): -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
F/crashpad(25798): -----BEGIN CRASHPAD MINIDUMP-----
```